# Saving Image Path in SQL server 

Tags: asp.net, images, sql

I want to know a proper way of saving image path to SQL server when working with ASP.net.
I'm using SQL server 2005 & VB 2008.

Comment: What do you mean by "image path"?

Comment: i mean where the Image file is located in the PC `C:\Users\Cheezy\Desktop\imagename` like that

Comment: Where does the image come from? Is it hardcoded into the asp page? Has someone uploaded it? Can you give us some sample code?

Comment: @paulmorriss take a example like updating your picture in a profile.nope not hardcoded.i want to upload the image then save it to the image folder and save that path to the SQL server.sorry at the moment i don have any sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've uploaded it will be somewhere in your webroot most likely (unless you specify otherwise)

What I've done in the past for this type of thing (using PHP though) is rename the file to something that will be unique if they're all going into the same directory (like add the timestamp to the image name at the beginning.

Then once you have that name, write only it to your DB as a varchar datatype.

When you need to call it, you should know the path where your upload script is storing the files, so you would just concat the name stored in the DB to the "img_root_path" or whatever you want to call your path to the files.